# Firefox download problems

Tags: windows-vista, firefox

I have Firefox 4.0 on Windows-Vista 32 bit. I have this problem of when I download a file from web, while the download is in progress, I can see the downloaded file in my download directory. But the moment the download is 100% complete, the download windows says Scanning for virus and then finishes download. It just is not there! (It might sound strange/stupid) but its happening)

I have noticed this on more than one ocassion. As a result I had to download many files 2 times. Strangely it happens fine at some times.

So I am not sure what is happening.

1. Strangely, in my firefox download window, I don't see the name of the file recently downloaded. The download window is blank. I can see the names of the recently downloaded files in an other computer/firefox download window. So I doubt something is amiss in my Firefox settings/ `about:config` or windows settings somewhere?

How can I see the names of the completed downloaded files still in the download window?

Any pointers useful.

Answer (score 0):

I also run into this sometimes. It will appear to scan for a virus forever. All I do is hit the "clear list" button in the download window to stop the virus scanning. Then I go into Windows Explorer and do indeed see my downloaded file is functional.

Comment: Thanks. so you forcibly close the download window as well while it says 'scanning for virus'? About my other question, i found one setting in Firefox->Show download history. Will see if that options helps in my first problem.